# Is this the standard behavior of PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

This works without warning:

```
function test($a)
{
    echo 1;
}
test(2, 1);
```

This will cause warning:

```
function test($a)
{
    echo 1;
}
test();
```

If it's standard, any reason for this?

Answer (score 15):

Because in the first example `test()` may use `func_get_args()` to access its arguments, so it shouldn't throw an error.

In the second example, the `$a` is not optional. If you want it to be optional, tack a default in the arguments signature like so

```
function test($a = 1)
{
    echo 1;
}
test();
```

So yes, it is default behaviour, and it makes sense once you know the above.

### Concerning Edit

In the edited first example, you will be able to access `2` as `$a`, however the `1` will *only* be accessible via `func_get_args()` (or one of its similar functions like `func_get_arg()`).

Comment: I changed a little so that you guys shouldn't focus on the function not receiving a parameter

Comment: @wamp Not sure what your edit changes. This answer still stands.

Answer (score 1):

That is the correct behavior. Your function declaration states that it is expecting one argument. If you want to make a function argument optional, you should apply a default value. Otherwise you will raise an exception. Read the PHP documentation on [Function Arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) for full details on how to declare your functions and the ways you can pass in values.

[Edit] This should work fine for you:

```
function test($a = null)
{
    echo 1;
}
test();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just speculating, but a function not receiving a parameter it's expecting is potentially more dangerous than a function receiving an extra parameter it can safely ignore.

Also, I wonder if it might have something to do with the fact that PHP will let you declare defaults for the parameter values, so the warning may be to prevent a situation where you've just forgotten to give $a a default